# iOS 17 - Navigation Bar is not immediately visible when adding Navigation Controller in Xcode 15

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add navigation to my iOS app. I am simulating an iPhone 15 with iOS 17 on Xcode 15 and Swift 5.8.

I have seen in several tutorials that when Navigation Controller is added to storyboard via Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller a Navigation Bar should be immediately visible on the preview, like this:
[image: iPhone preview with Navigation Bar]

But instead I cannot see anything:
[image: iPhone preview without Navigation Bar]

I did not change any property of the Navigation Bar (that actually appeared on the view hierarchy by the way).
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default appearance of navigation bars is changed in iOS 15. From [TN3106](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3106-customizing-uinavigationbar-appearance):

> `UINavigationBar` in iOS 15 introduces changes to its appearance settings. It extends the usage of its `scrollEdgeAppearance`, which by default produces a transparent background, to all navigation bar styles.

Now navigation bars have a transparent background by default, which is why you can't see it.

You should use the `UINavigationBarAppearance` API to configure navigation bars. To get a translucent background like before, you should assign a `UINavigationBarAppearance`, configured with "default background" to `navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance`.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

If this is nil (the default), a transparent version of the `standardAppearance` will be used.

To do this in the storyboard, you can select the navigation bar in the hierarchy, and check the "scroll edge" checkbox:

[image]

Note that the navigation bar for the view controllers connected to the `UINavigationController` would still incorrectly show a transparent navigation bar (not sure if this is intentional). It does exhibit the expected behaviour when you build and run the app.

See [TN3106](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3106-customizing-uinavigationbar-appearance) for more ways you can customise the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for