# UINavigationController is black in run mode

Tags: ios, uikit

I have this old project where I present UINavigationController modally from rootController. When I run project from Xcode everything is fine. However, when run the same from simulator or device, the navigation bar is black. `isTranslucent = false` and `safeAreaInsets.top = 0`.

I disabled everything I could but this behaviour is continuing. New project from scratch did not show such error. What can it be? Maybe some settings or compiler flags that working properly in debug mode?

[image]

Comment: There has been some changes to how to set the appearance of the navigation bar. See the [`UINavigationBarAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance) APIs. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77284654/5133585) might also be relevant. That said, you should show a [mcve] and describe how you want your navigation bar to look like.